# Un par de dudas sobre el Bottom Navigation View en Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo un par de dudas sobre este componente de Android, aunque también se aplica a otros, pero bueno, he querido poner esto de ejemplo. Tengo el siguiente listener para los diferentes opciones de un Bottom Navigation View en el que estoy cargando cada fragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    bottom_navigation_view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->

        var fragment: Fragment? = null

        when (menuItem.itemId) {

            R.id.action_music -> {
                fragment = MusicFragment()
                openFragment(fragment)
                true
            }
            R.id.action_books -> {
                fragment = BooksFragment()
                openFragment(fragment)
                true
            }
            R.id.action_films -> {
                fragment = MoviesFragment()
                openFragment(fragment)
                true
            }

            else -> false
        }

    }

    bottom_navigation_view.selectedItemId = R.id.action_music

}

private fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

He visto en otros ejemplos por internet que en cada fragment crean un `companion object` con una función `newInstance` que devuelven el propio fragment:

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(): MusicFragment = MusicFragment()
}
```

¿Cual es la diferencia de hacerlo como lo he hecho en mi código o con el newInstance? Por otro lado me gustaría saber en el `when` para que se pone el true o false al final de cada opción? ¿Cual sería la diferencia si pongo false?

Comment: Hola Isaac. En Kotlin no se como funciona ya que en Android programo en Java pero antiguamente al cargar un fragmento si que hacias MoviesFragment frag = new MoviesFragment();  Esto Google lo quito y dice que asi no es como tienes que crear un Fragment ya que ahora te ponen la funcion NewInstance. Esto se creo porque al crear el fragmento i pasarle valores consumia bastante memoria i con el newinstance le pasas los valores por el arguments. Despues si tiene que recuperar un fragmento i el detecta que esta instanciado no tienes que volverlo a crear i gastar mas memoria.

Comment: Entonces lo que estoy haciendo con mi código es cargar una nueva instancia del fragmento cada vez que cargo este, cierto?

Answer (score 1):

> Cual es la diferencia de hacerlo como lo he hecho en mi código o con
>   el newInstance?

En realidad  es principalmente se debe a la ventajas:

**1)** De poder nuestro Fragment recibir valores creando un método estático `newInstance()` el cual recibe un Bundle, de esta forma no estarías modificando tu constructor.

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(Bundle args){
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        if(args != null){
            f.setArguments(args);
        }
        return f;
    }
```

En caso de no enviar valores simplemente sabemos que la clase Fragment crea un constructor por default el cual sería usado en este caso.

**2)** Si el sistema operativo recrea el fragmento y este necesita valores, se llamaría al constructor sin argumentos, en este caso se tendría que sobrecargar el constructor para agregar los valores necesarios lo cual no es una práctica correcta.

---

> me gustaría saber en el `when` para que se pone el true o false al final
>   de cada opción? ¿Cual sería la diferencia si pongo false?

La expresión [when](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html) no necesita un valor de retorno pero si tu listener `OnNavigationItemSelected`. En algunos listeners, el valor booleano de retorno determina si el evento se consume o no.

• `true` si el listener ha consumido el evento.

• `false` si no ha consumido el evento.

Si únicamente si devuelve true, se procesa el evento de seleccionar el elemento.